# Hyper-V 2012 EAL 4 certified

Tags: security, hyper-v-server-2012

Is the Hyper-V 2012 (R2) hypervisor EAL4 certfified?

I only found an EAL4 certification for Hyper-V 2008, but not for newer products.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Common Criteria Certified Product](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/products_OS.html#OS) page, it [is not](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/st_vid10520-vr.pdf) (PDF Warning).

The first link gives information on the certification, the PDF goes deep into the actual audit itself.

The specific component, Windows Hyper-V 2012, has not yet been evaluated.

Comment: I tried to interpret the pdf, but it is quite dense. Where can I see for which level Window 2012 had been certified?